# optimizing binary arithmetic operations using move semantics

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm experimenting with the `rvalue` references with a simple `Vector` class, trying to eliminate unneeded temporaries in binary operations. After a little bit of struggle, I found that with the following two overloads for `operator+()`:

```
// overload called if right = lvalue and left = lvalue/rvalue
friend Vector<T> operator+(Vector<T> a, const Vector<T>& b) {
  a += b;
  return a;
}

// overload called if right = rvalue and left = lvalue/rvalue
friend Vector<T> operator+(const Vector<T>& a, Vector<T>&& b) {
  b += a;
  return std::move(b);
}
```

I can ensure that in an expression like `auto x = a+b+c+d+...;`, as long as at least `a` or `b` is a temporary, the move constructor will be called without creating any new temporaries.

On the other hand even if one of the values after `a` and `b` (say `d`) is `lvalue`, that should technically be enough to avoid the copy. Is there any optimization that can compiler can do by scanning a given expression to find at least one temporary and start calling the `operator+` based on that value?

Example 1:

```
#include "vector.h"

Vector<double> get() {
  return {0, 1, 2, 6};
}
int main (){
  auto a = get();
  auto b = get();
  auto c = a + get() + b;
  std::cout << c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
calling move ctor
calling move ctor
[0, 3, 6, 18]
```

Example 2:

```
#include "vector.h"

Vector<double> get() {
  return {0, 1, 2, 6};
}
int main (){
  auto a = get();
  auto b = get();
  auto c = a + b + get();
  std::cout << c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
calling copy ctor
calling move ctor
[0, 3, 6, 18]
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to write `sum(a,b,get() )` instead of `operator+(a, operator+(b, get() ) )`? That way you have the lvale/rvalue information for each part of the expression, but it will get ugly once you start to deal with arbitrary expressions (I'm thinking of building an expression tree like in http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is negative. In your code

```
auto c = a + b + get();
```

The compiler must first call operator+() on a and b. This execution order is predefined in laguage specification I think. The compiler should not execute b + get() first, because different execution order can result in different return value for (a + b + get()), along with different side effects. So the order of execution should remain unchaged.

And is there something compiler can do with a + b part in the first place? As both a and b are l-value, compiler must choose a function which takes two l-value argumenets. It's not that compiler developers cannot add new optimizations, but that compiler should only do as specified in language. Suppose that compiler uses r-value version of your function for a + b. And then, in your function, a or b will be modified (as they are r-value), which is something not intended: why do we need to modify operands to get the sum of them?

And if you are willing to make a and b modifiable in your function, just can cast them as r-value before calling your function, like `std::move(a) + std::move(b) + get()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess you meant `std::move(a)` instead of `a.move()`?

Comment: You can always edit your answers. I fixed it, anyway.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know one can edit other's answer as well!